# How to serve up a JSON response using Go?

Tags: json, go

**Question:** Currently I'm printing out my response in the `func Index`
like this `fmt.Fprintf(w, string(response))` **however, how can I send JSON properly in the request so that it maybe consumed by a view?**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Payload struct {
    Stuff Data
}
type Data struct {
    Fruit Fruits
    Veggies Vegetables
}
type Fruits map[string]int
type Vegetables map[string]int


func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    response, err := getJsonResponse();
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(response))
}


func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Index)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func getJsonResponse()([]byte, error) {
    fruits := make(map[string]int)
    fruits["Apples"] = 25
    fruits["Oranges"] = 10

    vegetables := make(map[string]int)
    vegetables["Carrats"] = 10
    vegetables["Beets"] = 0

    d := Data{fruits, vegetables}
    p := Payload{d}

    return json.MarshalIndent(p, "", "  ")
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/unrolled/render may also help.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You can set your content-type header so clients know to expect json

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

Another way to marshal a struct to json is to build an encoder using the `http.ResponseWriter`

```
// get a payload p := Payload{d}
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(p)
```

Comment: While `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")` is correct for setting the content type, it doesn't when using `json.NewEncoder` instead i get a txt/plain result. Is anyone else getting this. The answer from @poorva worked as expected

Comment: Scratch that. If i use `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOk) ` I get the above result.

Comment: If I use `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOk)` then I get `text/plain; charset=utf-8`, if I dont set the Status-Code explicitly I get `applicaton/json` and the Response has still a Status-Code 200.

Comment: Hmmm ... could it have to do with the docs [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter)?  `Changing the header map after a call to WriteHeader (or Write) has no effect unless the modified headers are trailers.`

Comment: Adding `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")` above `json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(p)` work for me

Comment: @RamonRambo adding w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json") above w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOk) worked for me.

Comment: The problem with this answer is... What if the Encode fails?
Sadly, it can happen, for example if a float64 value is NaN!
It will return a 200 without body, and you'll find yourself yelling "WHAT THE HELL" to your code.
We should check the response value, but in that case, we could not change the Header no more... a dog chasing its own tail...
If you care about your sanity, please use @poorva response.

Comment: Another subtle difference is that the encoder will add a newline at the end of the HTTP Body as part of the payload (content length). This does not happen if json.Marshal() & w.write() is used as outlined in the answer post by @poorva

Answer (score 79):

Other users were commenting that the `Content-Type` is `plain/text` when encoding.
You have to set the content type with `w.Header().Set()` first, then write the HTTP response code with `w.WriteHeader()`.

If you call `w.WriteHeader()` first, then call `w.Header().Set()` after you will get `plain/text`.

An example handler might look like this:

```
func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := SomeStruct{}
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(data)
}
```

Comment: How to return response , if my program panics ? I tried using recover() , then returning from their but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 51):

You can do something like this in you `getJsonResponse` function -

```
jData, err := json.Marshal(Data)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
w.Write(jData)
```

Comment: One important note about this version is that it uses a byte slice in `jData`, possibly unnecessarily.
`Data` can be of arbitrary size, depending on the data being marshalled, so this could be a non-trivial memory waster.

After marshalling, we copy from memory to the `ResponseWriter` stream. The answer that uses json.NewEncoder() etc. would write the marshalled JSON straight into the `ResponseWriter` (into its stream ..)

Comment: Worked for me! Faced the issue when 'w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)' was added before or after.

Comment: No need to return after panic as this exits your program

Comment: At least this solution doesn't add the trailing \n of the `Encoder.Encode()` function

Comment: @Jonno you are right, but it's the only answer when you can check the encode goes well BEFORE writing the header, because once written it can be changed!

Comment: This is the only safe answer!

Answer (score 3):

In gobuffalo.io framework I got it to work like this:

```
// say we are in some resource Show action
// some code is omitted
user := &models.User{}
if c.Request().Header.Get("Content-type") == "application/json" {
    return c.Render(200, r.JSON(user))
} else {
    // Make user available inside the html template
    c.Set("user", user)
    return c.Render(200, r.HTML("users/show.html"))
}
```

and then when I want to get JSON response for that resource I have to set "Content-type" to "application/json" and it works.

I think Rails has more convenient way to handle multiple response types, I didn't see the same in gobuffalo so far.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this [package renderer](https://github.com/thedevsaddam/renderer), I have written to solve this kind of problem, it's a wrapper to serve JSON, JSONP, XML, HTML etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complement answer with a proper example:

```
func (ch captureHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case http.MethodPost:
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("error reading request body, %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        ...do your stuff here...
    case http.MethodGet:
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode( ...put your object here...)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("error building the response, %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    default:
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("method %s is not allowed", r.Method), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }
}
```